# Pass EJS variable to app.post node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have ejs file with variable like this:

```
<form action="/profile" method="post">
<p>
    <% var ten = user.username %>
    <strong>id</strong>: <%= user.id %><br>
    <strong>username</strong>: <%= ten %><br>
    <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.password %>
</p>
<p id="passwd" name="passwd" ><%= user.username %></p>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Wallet</button>
</form>
```

And in index.js file, I have POST request want to take variable "`ten`" and add to `password` variable like this.

```
this.app.post('/profile', (req, res) => {                        
            let password = req.body.ten;            
            let newWallet = operator.createWalletFromPassword(password);
            let projectedWallet = projectWallet(newWallet);
            res.status(201).send(projectedWallet)
        });
```

But it doesn't work. I even try to use:

```
let password = req.body.passwd;  
let password = req.body[passwd];
```

but it still not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use form element like input, select, textarea, etc. If you don't like to make it visible then use hidden type as following

```
<form action="/profile" method="post">
    <p>
        <% var ten = user.username %>
        <strong>id</strong>: <%= user.id %><br>
        <strong>username</strong>: <%= ten %><br>
        <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.password %>
    </p>
    <p id="passwd" name="passwd" ><%= user.username %></p>
    <!-- these fields will be sent to server -->
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%= user.username %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<%= user.password %>">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Wallet</button>
</form>
```